# SpringDataRestAdapter load child resources

Tags: angularjs, spring, hateoas

[image]

Hi there, I'm using SpringDataRestAdapter to interact with my spring data rest api. From the screen shot you can see that I've just loaded all the questions and I'm attempting to load their answers (one-to-many) relationship. In the debug window the _embeddedItems array is an array of Questions with _links to each questions answers. I'm trying to prompt SpringDataRestAdapter to autoload the answers by passing 'answers' as an argument to the processWithPromise call but to no avail.

The urls look like
http://localhost:8080/api/questions
http://localhost:8080/api/question/1/answers

The Question.loadAnswers(question) call is commented out... It works in that it loads the question's answers but I felt I was using the framework incorrectly.

Here is the method

```
Question.loadAnswers = function (question) {

            question.answers = question.answers? question.answers : [];

            angular.forEach(question._links.answers, function (answerLink) {
                var deferred = $http.get(answerLink);
                return SpringDataRestAdapter.processWithPromise(deferred).then(function (data) {
                    question.answers = data._embeddedItems;
                });
            });
        };
```

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at this answer on the corresponding Github issue here https://github.com/guylabs/angular-spring-data-rest/issues/22.

Thanks and regards,

Guy